# Combining surround stems to proper order -- Wave Agent can't handle large files?

Tags: mixing, surround-sound, exporting

ProTools exports surround mixes as LCRLsRsLFE but I need to send as LRCLFELsRs.  Usually I use Wave Agent to combine the mono stems in the proper order but it won't handle files over 4gb.  Anyone know a better way to do this exporting?

TIA!

Comment: Hi can you change your title into a question please ?! Best!

Answer (score 0):

Re-import the files to protools, make 6 mono tracks, copy your file into those tracks and reorder them to the desired order. Then copy the audio back onto your 5.1 track. Consolidate selection. Then export as interleaved file from the clip list.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that Wave Agent cannot export wav files larger than 4 GB is due to wav file format specifications. You therefore need to export to another file format, an option that Wave Agent does not offer.

A possible solution is to use [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/) to export your audio to rf64 file format and mapping channels at the same time.

- Import your 6 mono wav files into audacity on separate mono tracks.
- Check audacity preferences settings : Import/Export > When exporting to a file > Use personalized mix (Sorry, this is an approximate translation as I am using a non english version of audacity)
- File > Export > Select 'Other uncompressed formats' and under 'options', select 'RF 64'
- A window showing the mapping between project's tracks and output file appears. You can edit the mapping here.
- *Voilà* !

You should nevertheless check that the next steps in your workflow can actually open rf64 files.